# Подключение к закрытому удалённому репозиторию

Tags: c#, git, консоль, git-commit

**Добрый день!**

У меня есть приватный репозиторий. Мне нужно к нему подключиться, чтобы выбрать из него hash-коммита последнего. С публичным репозиторием всё получаеться, без авторизации. А с приватным нужна авторизация.

Помогите реализовать подключение к закрытому репозиторию с помощью библиотеки LibGit2Sharp.

Comment: На то репозиторий и закрытый, чтобы доступ к нему получить только с наличием логина и пароля

Comment: @Umed У меня есть логин и пароль.

Comment: *git://login:password@site.example.com/path/repo.git* или по аналогии. В соответствующем RFC прописаны возможные комбинации URL/URI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё решено!
Ошибка была в незнании полностью сервера с репозиторием!

Comment: Показали бы как исправили кодом, а не словами...

Comment: Мне нужно было подключаться через HTTP и через другой порт.